# Is there a way to inject support for the F# Option type into ServiceStack?

Tags: f#, servicestack

***Updated below...***

I recently started experimenting with ServiceStack in F#, so naturally I started with [porting the Hello World sample](http://servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/):

```
open ServiceStack.ServiceHost
open ServiceStack.ServiceInterface
open ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints

[<CLIMutable; Route("/hello"); Route("/hello/{Name}")>]
type Hello = { Name : string }

[<CLIMutable>]
type HelloResponse = { Result : string }

type HelloService() =
    inherit Service()

    member x.Any(req:Hello) =
        box { Result = sprintf "Hello, %s!" req.Name }

type HelloAppHost() =
    inherit AppHostBase("Hello Web Services", typeof<HelloService>.Assembly)
    override x.Configure container = ()

type Global() =
    inherit System.Web.HttpApplication()

    member x.Application_Start() =
        let appHost = new HelloAppHost()
        appHost.Init()
```

That works great. It's very concise, easy to work with, I love it. However, I noticed that the routes defined in the sample allow for the `Name` parameter to not be included. Of course, `Hello, !` looks kind of lame as output. I could use `String.IsNullOrEmpty`, but it is idiomatic in F# to be explicit about things that are optional by using the [Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233245.aspx) type. So I modified my `Hello` type accordingly to see what would happen:

```
[<CLIMutable; Route("/hello"); Route("/hello/{Name}")>]
type Hello = { Name : string option }
```

As soon as I did this, the F# type system forced me to deal with the fact that `Name` might not have a value, so I changed `HelloService` to this to get everything to compile:

```
type HelloService() =
    inherit Service()

    member x.Any(req:Hello) =
        box { Result = 
                match req.Name with
                | Some name -> sprintf "Hello, %s!" name
                | None -> "Hello!" }
```

This compiles, and runs perfectly when I don't supply a `Name` parameter. However, when I do supply a name...

> KeyValueDataContractDeserializer: Error converting to type: Type
>   definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type
>   'FSharpOption`1', got string starting with: World

This wasn't a complete surprise of course, but it brings me to my question:

It would be trivial for me to write a function that can wrap an instance of type `T` into an instance of type `FSharpOption<T>`. **Are there any hooks in ServiceStack that would let me provide such a function for use during deserialization?** I looked, but I couldn't find any, and I'm hoping I was just looking in the wrong place.

This is more important for F# use than it might seem at first, because classes defined in F# are by default not allowed to be null. So the only (satisfying, non-hacky) way of having one class as an optional property of another class is with, you guessed it, the Option type.

---

***Update:***

I was able to sort-of get this working by making the following changes:

In the ServiceStack source, I made this type public:
`ServiceStack.Text.Common.ParseFactoryDelegate`

...and I also made this field public:
`ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader.ParseFnCache`

With those two things public, I was able to write this code in F# to modify the `ParseFnCache` dictionary. I had to run this code prior to creating an instance of my AppHost - it didn't work if I ran it inside the AppHost's `Configure` method.

```
JsvReader.ParseFnCache.[typeof<Option<string>>] <- 
    ParseFactoryDelegate(fun () -> 
        ParseStringDelegate(fun s -> (if String.IsNullOrEmpty s then None else Some s) |> box))
```

This works for my original test case, but aside from the fact that I had to make brittle changes to the internals of ServiceStack, it sucks because I have to do it once for each type I want to be able to wrap in an `Option<T>`.

What would be better is if I could do this in a generic way. In C# terms, it would be awesome if I could provide to ServiceStack a `Func<T, Option<T>>` and ServiceStack would, when deserializing a property whose generic type definition matches that of the return type of my function, deserialize `T` and then pass the result into my function.

Something like that would be amazingly convenient, but I could live with the once-per-wrapped-type approach if it were actually part of ServiceStack and not my ugly hack that probably breaks something somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are a couple of extensibility points in ServiceStack, on the framework level you can add your own [Custom Request Binder](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization) this allows you to provide your own model binder that's used, e.g:

```
base.RequestBinders.Add(typeof(Hello), httpReq => {
    var requestDto = ...;
    return requestDto;
});
```

But then you would need to handle the model binding for the different Content-Types yourself, see [CreateContentTypeRequest](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Support/EndpointHandlerBase.cs#L91) for how ServiceStack does it.

Then there are hooks at the JSON Serializer level, e.g:

```
JsConfig<Hello>.OnDeserializedFn = dto => newDto;
```

This lets you modify the instance of the type returned, but it still needs to be the same type but it looks like the F# option modifier changes the structural definition of the type?

But I'm open to adding any hooks that would make ServiceStack more palatable for F#. 
What does the code look like to generically convert a normal `Hello` type to an F# `Hello` type with option?

Comment: Converting an entire `Hello` type without an option into one with an option in a generic manner seems awfully ambitious. What I was imagining is a way to tell the deserializer, "When you encounter a property with the generic type `FSharpOption<>`, pass the regular deserialized value into the function I'm providing to get the value that should be assigned to the property. The two values I would pass into such a hook would be `typedefof<Option<_>>` (the Option type in F# code is exposed to C# as FSharpOption) and `fun x -> Some x`.

Comment: Also, option isn't so much a modifier as a new type. It's the difference between `string` and `Option<string>` - the syntax `string option` is just a different way of expressing `Option<string>`. Think of it like `Nullable<>` in C#, except it works on any type and not just value types.

Comment: To put it another way, the C# signature for the hook I'm imagining would look something like `AddPropertyConverter<TProp, TVal>(Func<TVal, TProp>)`. In my F# code I would then call it with `AddPropertyConverter<string option, string>(fun x -> Some x)`

Comment: If Option is a struct/ValueType then you should be able to do `JsConfig<Option<string>>.DeserializeFn = str => /*Option<string> value*/`

Comment: @mythz : Option is a reference type.

Comment: @mythz - I hacked the ServiceStack source to get my original scenario working, but it's a pale shadow of what it could be. See the update to my original question for details.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is to replace the option type with your own type, one that has an implicit conversion from `string` to `myOption`, and anything else you need.

Not all that nice, but workable. Your type would probably also need to be serializable.

```
type myOption = 
   | None 
   | Some of string
   static  member public op_Implicit (s:string) = if s <> null then Some s else None
   member public this.Value = match this with 
                              | Some s -> s
                              | _      -> null
   member this.Opt = match this with 
                     | Some s -> Option.Some s
                     | None   -> Option.None
```

Your record type would then be

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Hello = 
   { Name : myOption }
```

On the other hand, ServiceStack *is* open source, so maybe something could be done there.